# How do we move our civicrm SQL database from the cloud to our network?

Tags: database

We are running our CiviCSM system on a vendor's host with our database in the cloud.  We have a CiviCSM system built for our network that is not currently in use, but we want to move the database from the cloud to our network.  Can we Export/Import, Backup/Restore or Detach/Attach and which would work best?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your server and database, and you want to move the whole installation [this wiki page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) should provide all the information you need. If you only want to move the database, have a look at [this page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+the+database+using+phpMyAdmin).

I am assuming you are talking about CiviCRM, not CiviCSM ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, this isn't a CiviCRM question but a MySQL question.  MySQL is the database software that underpins CiviCRM.  Moving a MySQL database can be done either using the command line (`mysqldump`) or via web interface (`phpMyAdmin`).

However, this is a fairly technical process, and I wouldn't recommend trying this without someone experienced!  Fortunately, anyone with MySQL experience can help you, even if they've never seen CiviCRM before.  Just have them read the links in Fabian's answer.